# ms- excel : growing customer Highlight

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 month(Jan, Feb) sales for list of customers,  I want to highlight the sales which is lesser than prev month.

example:

```
Customer    Jan Feb
A           100 150
B           50  80
C           110 90
D           95  100
E           80  100
```

I want to highlight February month Sales only de-growing Customer.

Comment: For this, you need to look at using conditional formatting. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional formatting:

- select the month(s) you want to format
- in home tab select conditional formatting - new rule - "use a formula to determine which cell to format"
- enter formula `=B2>C2`

  - **important**: `C2` should be the active cell
- click "format" and set formatting as you need

[image]